# EDK2 Setup for ubuntu

Tags: uefi

I am working on EDK2 setup using 
[following link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/EDK2).When I tried to use build command under folder ~/src/edk2 for OVMF firmware image creation I am getting below error:

```
/home/sam/src/edk2/CryptoPkg/Library/OpensslLib/OpensslLibCrypto.inf(31): error 000E: File/directory not found in workspace
/home/sam/src/edk2/CryptoPkg/Library/OpensslLib/openssl/e_os.h
```

Answer (score 5):

Your repo is missing the openssl source code. Simply do

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```